# Confused on how $ \exp{\frac{1337 \pi i}{4}} = \exp{(167 \times 2 \pi i + \frac{\pi}{4}}i) $

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, exponential-function

We are attempting to express the following in the form $x + i\space y:$
$$ \left(\frac{i+1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^{1337} $$
The solution is expressed as such:
$$ \left(\frac{i+1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^{1337}=\left(\exp{\frac{i \pi}{4}} \right)^{1337} = \exp{\frac{1337 \pi i}{4}} = \exp{(167 \times 2 \pi i + \frac{\pi}{4}}i) = \exp{\frac{\pi}{4}i}=\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}$$
What I am unable to figure out  is this step in particular:
$$ \exp{\frac{1337 \pi i}{4}} = \exp{(167 \times 2 \pi i + \frac{\pi}{4}}i) $$
I  have tried to change the value within the LHS exponential to match the value within the RHS exponential, but I cannot figure out how the solution performs this step.
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: $\dfrac{1337}4 = 167\times 2 + \dfrac 14$. Divide the LHS by $2$, and write down the quotient and remainder.

Comment: $\exp (a+b)=\exp (a)\cdot \exp (b).$  And $\exp (2\pi i n)=1$ when $n\in\Bbb Z.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\left(167 \times 2+\frac14\right)\pi i=\left(\frac{167\times8+1}4\right)\pi i=\frac{1337}4\pi i$$

Answer (score 1):

> $$ \exp{\frac{1337 \pi i}{4}} = \exp{(167 \times 2 \pi i + \frac{\pi}{4}}i) $$

$$\frac{1337\pi i}{4}=\frac{1336\pi i+\pi i}{4}=\frac{1336\pi i}{4}+\frac{\pi}{4}i=334\pi i+\frac{\pi}{4}i=167\times 2\pi i+\frac{\pi}{4}i$$